# how to change JSON format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting ajax response json as follows

```
var optgroups = [{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER1","EQ_ID":"WKS1"},
{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER1","EQ_ID":"WKS2"},
{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER2","EQ_ID":"WKS3"},
{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER2","EQ_ID":"WKS4"}]
```

how to change this into the following format

```
 var optgroups = [
                          {
                              label: 'WKS-FINGER1', children: [
                                  {label: 'WKS1', value: 'WKS1',},
                                   {label: 'WKS2', value: 'WKS2',}

                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              label: 'WKS-FINGER2', children: [
                                  {label: 'WKS3', value: 'WKS3',},
                                   {label: 'WKS4', value: 'WK4',}
                              ]
                          }
                      ];
```

Comment: Looks like a for loop would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and build a new array.

The method utilizes `thisArgs` as a temporary object for the reference to the items.

```js
var optgroups = [{ "LAST_X_HRS": 1, "AREA": "WKS-FINGER1", "EQ_ID": "WKS1" }, { "LAST_X_HRS": 1, "AREA": "WKS-FINGER1", "EQ_ID": "WKS2" }, { "LAST_X_HRS": 1, "AREA": "WKS-FINGER2", "EQ_ID": "WKS3" }, { "LAST_X_HRS": 1, "AREA": "WKS-FINGER2", "EQ_ID": "WKS4" }],
    temp = [];

optgroups.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.AREA]) {
        this[a.AREA] = { label: a.AREA, children: [] };
        temp.push(this[a.AREA]);
    }
    this[a.AREA].children.push({ label: a.EQ_ID, value: a.EQ_ID });
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(temp, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach turns out to be very similar to @Nina Scholz indeed however when it comes to array reducing `Array.prototype.reduce()` just makes more sense to me.

```js
var optGroups = [{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER1","EQ_ID":"WKS1"},{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER1","EQ_ID":"WKS2"},{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER2","EQ_ID":"WKS3"},{"LAST_X_HRS":1,"AREA":"WKS-FINGER2","EQ_ID":"WKS4"}],
reduced = optGroups.reduce((p,c) => { var i = p.length-1;
                                     if (!!p[i] && p[i].label == c.AREA) {
                                       p[i].children.push({label: c.EQ_ID, value: c.EQ_ID});
                                     } else {
                                       p.push({label: c.AREA, children: []});
                                       p[++i].children.push({label: c.EQ_ID, value: c.EQ_ID});
                                       }
                                      return p; }, []);

document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(reduced, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```